# Using fungible Statemine assets with governance

Tags: governance, statemint, statemine, gov2

What is the best design to reuse governance pallets (e.g. treasury, council, Gov2) with non-L1 tokens?

Can a Statemine fungible asset be used with these pallets?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best design to reuse governance pallets (e.g. treasury, council, Gov2) with non-L1 tokens?

You'll want to look at the `pub trait Config { type Currency }` for each of the pallets you are interested in. Taking [Democracy for example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/279593d87f103fa5e10c9751a97b1584f3ad79d6/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L259L260), it requires the assets it uses to fulfill `ReservableCurrency` and `LockableCurrency`.

```rust
/// Currency type for this pallet.
type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>
    + LockableCurrency<Self::AccountId, Moment = Self::BlockNumber>;
```

Right now, the Assets pallet does not have implementations of these traits, although it is on the general roadmap.

> Can a Statemine fungible asset be used with these pallets?

Due to the limitations of the Assets pallet mentioned above, they couldn't be used *directly*. However, if your parachain recognizes Statemine as the reserve location for some asset, it could handle the `ReserveAssetDeposited` XCM instruction by minting some asset into a pallet that does implement those traits (e.g. Balances). In that case, the asset could be used for governance on your parachain.